# Delegate responds with NULL when it gets called from a second view

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios7, delegates

I've searched StackOverflow and google, but am still stuck.
Any help or code snippets appreciated!

So, the problem that I'm seeing is that my delegate responds only when called from the first instance of a custom view controller class (`AddJobViewController` based on `UIKit.h`). It works fine when called from the first view, however the delegate returns `null` when called by the second view.  Whichever view I segue to gets the delegate assigned correctly.
I have two views in the storyboard that have this custom class assigned.

Here is the code for delegation:

`ATableViewController.h`:

```
#import "AddJobViewController.h"

@interface ATableViewController : UITableViewController <AddJobViewControllerDelegate, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate>
```

ATableViewController.m:

```
- (void)AddJobViewControllerSave {
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.managedObjectContext;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Error! %@", error);
    }
}
```

Segue in `ATableViewController.m`:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"addJob"]) {
        AddJobViewController *ajvc = (AddJobViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        ajvc.delegate=self;

        AJobDetails *newJob = (AJobDetails *) [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"AJobDetails" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

        ajvc.currentJob = newJob;
    }
}
```

`AddJobViewController.h`:

```
#import "AJobDetails.h"

@protocol AddJobViewControllerDelegate;

@interface AddJobViewController : UIViewController

- (IBAction)save:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)next:(id)sender;

@end

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <AddJobViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

@property (nonatomic, strong) AJobDetails *currentJob;

@protocol AddJobViewControllerDelegate
-(void)AddJobViewControllerSave;
-(void)AddJobViewControllerNext;
-(void)AddJobViewControllerDidCancel:(AJobDetails *)jobToDelete;

@end
```

`AddJobViewController.m`:

```
- (IBAction)save:(id)sender {


    [self.currentJob setThresholdTrimText:thresholdText.text];

NSLog(@"PVC Delegate: %@",self.delegate);
    [self.delegate AddJobViewControllerSave];
}
```

The Core Data context is being passed to both views and works correctly.

Comment: Can you please clarify what is 'Second' view? Is it the second instance of the AddJobViewController class or something else? If it is the object of class AddJobViewController, then you should debug the method prepareForSegue: as I suspect it is not getting called second time.

Comment: The 'Second' view is the second instance of the AddJobViewController class. I've changed the prepareForSeque in AddJobViewController to: ` if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"addProduct"]) {
        AddJobViewController *apvc = (AddJobViewController *) [segue destinationViewController];
        apvc.currentJob = _currentJob;
        [apvc setDelegate:self.delegate];` and it now seems to work! Thank you! Is my change correct from a best practice point of view?

Comment: Glad it worked.I think it will do.